# insert html into sql

Tags: html, sql, database, oracle

I would like to insert the following into an oracle sql table, but i cant because of the single quotes. I know if i convert the single quotes to two single quotes it'll work, but i would like to do it all from sqlplus and not need to change it from notepad. Any suggestions.

```
set define off;

insert into test
values('<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><b>TEST
</b></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><b>Test</b></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'>&nbsp;</p>

<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><b><u>Test</u></b></p>')
```

Comment: set escape on; replace('''', '''''''');

Comment: I tried it and didnt seem to work for me. can you alter that code to show your explanation. thanks, i really hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

using : ''margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt''

''margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt''

''margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt''

''text-align:center''

this should work

Comment: I know this works. my question is if there's a script that'll make the changes for me.